# How to move image in input which is set with `background` property?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I set image (calendar) in input field, which i remove if date is entered:

`$("#validFromDateId").css("background", "url('"+imageURL+"') no-repeat left center");`

But it doesn't look very good:

[image]

Is it possible to move it a little bit in right, already tried with padding and margin, but it moveс only the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `left` property you can set some `px` (or any unit such `(r)em`)

```
$("#validFromDateId").css("background", "url('"+imageURL+"') no-repeat 10px center");
```

read more about `bg-position` in `background` shorthand [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#bg-position)